# Classic ASP & Java Applets

Tags: java, asp-classic, applet

Is it possible to fetch the values selected in Java Applet and pass the values to the classic ASP page.

For example: I have the main page in Classic ASP which invokes the Java Applet an allow the users to select the desired seats. Once the user has selected the seats and clicked on Add to Cart button in the applet, the values are passed to the classic ASP page to add the values in the fields.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want an answer to your question: Yes, that's possible. But it seems you are asking for a complete code sample. Show what you've tried first.

Comment: hi Tomalak, I am not asking for complete code. I am asking for concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
URL url = new URL(
    "addToCart.asp?" +
    "seat1=b32" +
    "&seat2=b33"
    );
getAppletContext().showDocument(url);
```